# Auto reload POST request on browser back button

Tags: javascript, html, browser

We have a web application developed on Spring MVC and Thymeleaf, where user lands on home page with a GET request. On home page, user enters 2 parameters and make a POST request. On successful submission, a new page (lets call it page2) open which have link to let say www.stackoverflow.com. User click on the link and comes to stackoverflow page. Now if user click on browser back button, browser states that this action requires form re-submission. On click of refresh button of browser, a pop appears to confirm re-submission and confirming it successfully open page2.

The problem is client dont want to have this popup or message page, instead want to auto resubmit the page on browser back button. Since the page from where the browser back button is clicked is out of my control, please guide how this can be done.

Note - 2 parameter entered on home page(page1) is not related with any authentication or login process.

Comment: You can get rid of the message by implementing the POST/Redirect/GET pattern; but you can not have it automatically submit the same data again without asking the user for confirmation. This is a safety/security feature - you don't want to actually order a second pizza from the online shop, just because you used the back button in their order frontend ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described by [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) PRG pattern is the correct solution. Adding this answer for those who are facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this on top of php page

```
header_remove("Expires");
header_remove("Cache-Control");
header_remove("Pragma");
header_remove("Last-Modified");
```